# Natural/Australian scrolling on Asus Chromebox

Tags: mouse, operating-systems, scrolling, google-chrome-os

I am using a Logitech T630 mouse on my Asus Chromebox and would like to enable Australian scolling. Unfortunately this option is not available in the mouse settings dialog. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake what is Australian scrolling? This is the first I have heard of it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek From [Ask GadgetGuy: what is Australian scrolling?](http://www.gadgetguy.com.au/ask-gadgetguy-what-is-australian-scrolling/) - "*Called "natural scrolling" over in the Mac OS camp, ["Australian scrolling" is Google's name for using the touchpad](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2583287) where your gesture for scrolling up actually flicks stuff on your screen down, and where flicking down scrolls – yep, you guessed it – straight up.*"